# EF6 SQLite Encryption with AES128/256

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, entity-framework-6, aes

We are developing a WPF desktop application using Entity Framework 6 with SQLite. At some point we decided to encrypt the database and I was looking for a solution. Following SQLiteConfiguration is applied to DataContext:

```
public class SQLiteConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SQLiteConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
    }
}
```

First thing that I tried for encryption:

```
string conn_str= @"data source=" + db_path + ";Version=3;";
conn.ConnectionString = conn_str;
conn.Open();
conn.ChangePassword(Const.PWD);
conn.Close();
```

That works as expected. Since we are using `System.Data.SQLite`, default encryption algorithm is RC4.

My question is that, is there any way to change encryption method to `AES128/AES256` ?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have built-in encryption. You need to use a custom extension for this. The current Microsoft driver is `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`. To [enable encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli) you need to add an extension. The encryption you get depends on that extension. The `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher` package adds the SQLCipher extension which uses AES256

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have read the documentation also. But for me it is not clear, using EF6 (not EF Core) with `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`. Should I remove all System.Data.SQLite and System.Data.SQLite.EF6 dlls and instead use  
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher?